# Running Concatenation of column values in oracle sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have table structure like below

```
create table emp ( empno number,dept_no varchar(4));
insert into emp VALUES  (1,'A');
insert into emp  VALUES (1,'B');
insert into emp  VALUES (1,'C');
insert into emp  VALUES (1,'D');
insert into emp  VALUES (2,'P');
insert into emp  VALUES (2,'Q');
insert into emp  VALUES (2,'R');
insert into emp  VALUES (2,'S');
```

I need output like below

```
1, A
1, A,B
1, A,B,C
1, A,B,C,D
2, P
2, P,Q
2, P,Q,R
2, P,Q,R,S
```

I am able to achieve this using PL/SQL Block, however is there any possibility we can achieve this through sql?

Comment: Where did those 10s and 20s come from?

Comment: Correct the output now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a task for `listagg()`. Unfortunately, although it can be used as window function, it does not support the `order by` window option, which is needed here.

One way to work around this would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    e.empno,
    (
            select listagg(e1.dept_no, ',') within group(order by e1.dept_no)
            from emp e1
            where e1.empno = e.empno and e1.dept_no <= e.dept_no            
    ) depts
from emp e
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=02d73fb1027de69ba934e527912cd4e4)**:

```
EMPNO | DEPTS  
----: | :------
    1 | A      
    1 | A,B    
    1 | A,B,C  
    1 | A,B,C,D
    2 | P      
    2 | P,Q    
    2 | P,Q,R  
    2 | P,Q,R,S
```

Comment: Can you please explain that final `/` after the `end;` in the fiddle? Without it, web site brings me error. Kindly thank you.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко: that's a trick to run the inserts in a batch. Otherwise, db<>fiddle wants each insert statement as a separate entry, which is tedious to write. Note: nice to see that you actually checked the fiddle!

Comment: I am thinking about... Is it possible to have this question answered with a recursive cte solution? But I have a serious issue for now. The recursive cte's only work in `postgres` for me. Nor did the "uk" web site, nor is the other web sites allow me to have a `recursive` syntax with the `Oracle`. Maybe, by coincedence, you know why it is so? At the end of my trial, I had copy/pasted the official Oracle docs(recursive example) from here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive. And there were errors still.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко: you are reading the MySQL documentation on Oracle website. Oracle does support [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm), and this is a viable option here; however I would expect that this would be less efficient than the correlated subquery solution.

Comment: My mistake. `Oracle` seems to omit the `recursive` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from good answer from @gmb, you can also try following option where table will be traverse only once.

```
SELECT empno,
    LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(dept_no,','),',') AS employees
FROM   (SELECT dept_no,
               empno,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empno ORDER BY dept_no) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empno ORDER BY dept_no) -1 AS prev
        FROM   emp)
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr
  AND empno = PRIOR empno
START WITH curr = 1;
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d680ba6b23b7d5c3c3fecdcb4e32778)

Cheers!!